# Multi Module Project gradle - multiple or single build.gradle

Tags: gradle

I've seen different layouts for a multi-module project where some will have a single `build.gradle` while others projects will have a `build.gradle` at the root and a `build.gradle` in each subproject. I was wondering what is the difference and which layout is preferred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single `build.grade` in the root project to inject configuration to all sub-projects using the **[`allprojects`](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:allprojects(groovy.lang.Closure))** or **[`subprojects`](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:subprojects(groovy.lang.Closure))** script blocks. This will work well for defining a common configuration for all projects/sub-projects and is mostly suitable where all projects are of the same type.

However, if some of the sub-projects needs to be further customized then the right place for these customization would be in the `build.gradle` file located in the sub-project folder.

You can read more about your options for configuring multi-project builds in gradle documentation **[here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)**, and some more information about your options in organizing your build logic in gradle user guild **[here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html)**.